# file .htaccess and css

Tags: .htaccess, model-view-controller, path

When I write my .htaccess file the css and js of my project don't work. I use the MVC pattern and in my mainController I `require_once` every time the view. I don't understand, why with .htaccess file the program tries to `require_once` also the js.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This is the console output:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "".
>
> jquery.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
> bootstrap.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Answer (score 0):

Please add mime header types in your .htaccess file, maybe it help

```
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js
```